# Python function to determine whether a given BST is valid

Tags: python, recursion, tree

Here's a simple function I wrote using recursion. Does this run in \$O(n)\$ time and use \$O(n)\$ space, where \$n\$ is the number of nodes in the tree?

```
def is_valid(root, min, max):
    if not root:
        return True
    if min is None or max is None:
        return is_valid(root, float("-inf"), float("+inf"))
    print(root.value, min, max)
    if root.value <= min:
        return False
    if root.value >= max:
        return False
    return is_valid(root.left, min, root.value) and is_valid(root.right, root.value, max)
```

Comment: I suggest removing the `print`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Stick with `None`**

One of the things you do is effectively convert `None`s into `-inf` and `+inf`. But that's not necessary. Stick with `None`, and then you can ignore those comparisons. I would additionally explicitly default the arguments:

```
def is_valid(root, min=None, max=None):
    if not root:
        return True
    if min is not None and root.value <= min:
        return False
    if max is not None and root.value >= max:
        return False
    return is_valid(root.left, min, root.value) and is_valid(root.right, root.value, max)
```

I also removed the `print` - since you don't really want random output as you go through your function.

Besides that, looks good to me. The last line is a bit long, so I might wrap it in parentheses just so I can do:

```
    return (is_valid(root.left, min, root.value) and 
            is_valid(root.right, root.value, max))
```

Try to keep your lines below 80 characters.

---

An alternate implementation, just throwing it out as an idea for thinking about the problem *completely* differently is this. A BST is valid if it's in-order traversal is actually ordered. An in-order traversal would be:

```
def traverse_in_order(root):
    if root:
        yield from traverse_in_order(root.left)
        yield root.value
        yield from traverse_in_order(root.right)
```

In Python2.7, replace `yield from X` with `for x in X: yield x`. Basically, we're turning our tree into an iterable. Then, we can just pairwise iterate over this with some `itertools` [recipes](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes):

```
def pairwise(iterable):
    "s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ..."
    a, b = tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return izip(a, b)
```

And just check that every pair is in strictly increasing order:

```
def is_valid(root):
    return all(i < j for i,j in pairwise(traverse_in_order(root)))
```

Not saying this is better than your original approach, but it's certainly different.

Comment: When you say min=None does that automatically set min to None if a parameter wasn't given?

Comment: @DanielJacobson Yep. See [Default Argument Values](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#default-argument-values)

Answer (score 1):

`is_valid` isn't a particularly informative name unless this will be attached to a class. `is_valid_bst` would be better and reads clearer when used:

```
if is_valid_bst(my_data, 0, 100):
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be a bug. If you have `min=None` and `max=5` then `max` is set to `+inf` instead of `5`.